# Deploy a single EAR in JBOSS EAP 6.3

Tags: jboss-eap-6

I need to deploy an ear in jboss eap6.3 but I don't want to place it in any folder and let deployment-scanner do it for me.

Is there a way to mention the EAR file that I need to deploy rather than whole directory?

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy your ear using the JBoss Command Line Interface (CLI):

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.exe --connect --controller=127.0.0.1:9999 --user=manager --password=password deploy path/to/your.ear
```

This can be scripted if required. Undeploying is the same:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.exe --connect --controller=127.0.0.1:9999 --user=manager --password=password undeploy your.ear
```